# What's the difference between launching with an API call vs the triple-chevron syntax?

Tags: cuda, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

Consider the following two function templates:

```
template <typename... Params>
void foo(Params... params)
{
    /* etc etc */
    my_kernel<<<grid_dims, block_dims, shmem_size, stream_id>>>(params...);
}
```

and:

```
template <typename... Params> 
void bar(Params... params)
{
    /* etc etc */
    void* arguments_ptrs[sizeof...(Params)];
    auto arg_index = 0;

    for_each_argument(
        [&](auto param) {arguments_ptrs[arg_index++] = &param;},
        params...);

    cudaLaunchKernel<decltype(my_kernel)>(
        &my_kernel, grid_dims, block_dims, argument_ptrs, shmem_size, stream_id);
}
```

with `for_each_argument` being as [defined](https://twitter.com/SeanParent/status/558330478541803522) by Sean Parent.

Questions:

- Are the semantics of `foo` and `bar` exactly identical?
- Is there some kind of benefit to using one over the other? (e.g. perhaps the first form does heap allocation under the hood or something....)
- Is it a good idea to use forwarding references in the second function? Both functions?

Answer (score 1):

> Are the semantics of foo and bar exactly identical?

I haven't checked in CUDA 9, but prior to that, no. The `<<<>>>` syntax is inline expanded to an API call and a wrapper function call. Interestingly the kernel launch APIs used are [long deprecated](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION__DEPRECATED.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION__DEPRECATED_1g48ce0897c5f2bae491a555970063903a). But the wrapper function allows for explicit argument type safety checking at compile time, which is helpful.

[EDIT: I checked CUDA 9.1 and it still uses `cudaLaunch` as all previous versions of the runtime API did]

> Is there some kind of benefit to using one over the other? (e.g. perhaps the first form does heap allocation under the hood or something....)

Not that I am aware of.

> Is it a good idea to use forwarding references in the second function? Both functions?

If the kernels are compiled at the same compilation unit scope as the calling code, then no. The toolchain automatically emits forward declarations for kernels .

Comment: The deprecated launch API you linked to isn't the one I've used; mine is [not marked deprecated](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g5064cdf5d8e6741ace56fd8be951783c). Or - do you mean the one that the chveron is expanded to? Also, from the last part of your reply I gather that `bar` should have forwarding references to bring it closer to `foo`. Good point about the type safety check. Is it possible to see what the chevron is expanded to?

Comment: I never said it was. I said your approach and what the toolchain does are not the same, precisely because the toolchain relies on a different API

Comment: And you can see exactly what the toolchain does in my answer on your other related question

Answer (score 0):

Remember that, eventually, the runtime API needs to make driver API calls (assuming it doesn't make *secret API* calls which we don't know about), so eventually, what's used is [`cuLaunchKernel()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gb8f3dc3031b40da29d5f9a7139e52e15):

```cuda
CUresult cuLaunchKernel ( 
    CUfunction f, 
    unsigned int  gridDimX, 
    unsigned int  gridDimY,
    unsigned int  gridDimZ, 
    unsigned int  blockDimX,
    unsigned int  blockDimY, 
    unsigned int  blockDimZ,
    unsigned int  sharedMemBytes,
    CUstream hStream, 
    void** kernelParams, 
    void** extra )
```

and that's a non-templated interface which doesn't care about kinds-of-references and such.

Of course, there is the fact that there are two ways to specify launch arguments - using `kernelParams` and using `extra`. So if you want to tweak how you go about launching kernels, you might just want to play with that.